# Using the uv4l driver to stream and record to a file simultaneously

Tags: streaming-video, uv4l

I need to record video from the pi's inbuilt camera  at the same time as streaming it.

One way to do this (using "tee") is described here [record and stream video from camera simultaneously](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/record-and-stream-video-from-camera-simultaneously). It works for me, but the latency when viewing the stream is poor (5 seconds +).

I've also experimented with the user space driver uv4l, which provides good low latency video streaming from my raspberry pi (<1 s delay). http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=190. However that driver doesn't seem to lend itself to the "tee" approach.

Is there a way I can use the uv4l driver to both record to a file and stream simultaneously?

Comment: I don't see why something like 'dd if=/dev/video0' piped to 'tee' would not work, if it worked for you with raspivid. the principle is the same.

Comment: Could you give a command line to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone, I never managed to get this working using uv4l. Shame, as uv4l was the only approach I tried that could stream from the pi in near real-time to a browser.

I did find an alternate solution based on http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=150 that worked for me, but viewing the stream requires gstreamer instead of a browser on the viewing machine. That's OK for my needs.

On the pi I used rapivid, and teed the output to both gstreamer and a local file:

```
raspivid -vf -t 0 -w 640 -h 480 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | tee test_video.h264 | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=10.0.0.239 port=5000
```

I viewed the stream on my laptop, and found the stream to be good quality and low lag (maybe < .3s latency, not measured).

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=10.0.0.239 port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

I also used iptraf to check the network traffic out of the pi, it seems to hover around 900kbps - 1Mbps. Bumping the resolution increases this as you would expect. top shows very low cpu usage.

Then to check the quality of the recorded file I made an mp4 file.

```
MP4Box -add test_video.h264 -fps 25 test_video.mp4
```

I opened the file in chrome - the quality seems just as good as the stream.